# How do I sign-in on twitter by php script?

Tags: php, authentication, twitter-oauth, access-token, autologin

How do I sign-in on twitter by php script? (I don't want to use the login page)
I use PHP/OAuth (http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth).
I would like to login (by php) to use in automatically another Twitter-application.

how can I retrieve 'access_token' & 'oauth_token_secret'?

---

1) thank's but the problem is: "**TEMPORARY** credentials"...

Whenever the data changes.
example:

```
/* first */
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken('http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.php');
echo $request_token['oauth_token']."<br>"; /* == 1213hfktyititff */
echo $request_token['oauth_token_secret']."<br>"; /* == ttjkhklkutltu */

/* second*/
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken('http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.php');
echo $request_token['oauth_token']."<br>"; /* == kjregntrury89r */
echo $request_token['oauth_token_secret']."<br>"; /* == 87r86rbw7brywgewgwr */
```

---

2)thanks but I would like to use an application of another person => I do not have infinite lifetime for my oauth_token & secret :(

Comment: Possible [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+twitter+login)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.matpal.com/2010/12/login-with-twitter-api-in-php.html) should do what you need:

```
<?php

require_once('twitteroauth.php');
/* Application Details */

$connection = new TwitterOAuth("----Your Consumer Key -----",
"------------Consumer Secret-------------");

/* Get temporary credentials. */
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

/* Save temporary credentials to session. */
$token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$secret= $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

 /* If last connection failed don't display authorization link. */
switch ($connection->http_code)
{
case 200:
/* Build authorize URL and redirect user to Twitter. */
   $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
   echo"<a href='". $url."'>Login With Twitter </a>";
   break;

default:
/* Show notification if something went wrong. */
   echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> > how can I retrieve 'access_token' & 'oauth_token_secret'?

You should register your application/website [here](https://dev.twitter.com/). You'll be given app id and app secret.
After that you get a token by using code

```
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);
$token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$secret= $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
```

As EdoDodo said